# Trying to pass data from execve child process to parent process in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent

I've been trying to use pipes in order to pass a value calculated in the child process(which is created by execve in the parent) but have been unable to figure out why data isn't being transferred over. It's my understanding that unless the close on exec flag is set on the pipe that the the pipe would still be shared across processes even though child process is created with a copy of data with a new stack, heap, etc?

The parent works by allowing the user to enter in a value to change a string and the string reassignment is done in the child process to be sent back to the parent.

Here is my code for the parent process:

```
if((pid = fork())) {
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("Fork error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }
    wait(&status);
} else {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    char* argv[] =  {"new string", variableToChange, NULL};

    ret = execve("newstringchildprocess", argv, environ);
    close(fd[1]);
    int nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
    printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
    close(fd[0]);
}
```

And the child process(seperate C file):

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
char readbuffer[100];

close(fd[0]);
printf("Enter new string: ");
write(fd[1], variableToChange, (strlen(variableToChange) + 1));
int charCount = sizeof argv[0];
variableToChange = (char*) malloc(charCount);
close(fd[1]);
wait(NULL);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Currently I only get output from the child process if I remove the pipes code from both files. Any help would be great

Comment: You're calling `pipe` after the `fork`.

Comment: There's no point having any code after `exec*` except error handling.  `exec*` does not return unless it fails.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can't believe I wasted almost an hour because I did this exact same thing...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is to connect your child's output to the father.

One way for doing this is piping, of course, but you have to create the pipe in the father process and then forking, so the child is going to inherit the opened pipe.

Oh, and If I'm not wrong, after `execve` the process "dies" as it does not comes back to your code.

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Fork error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
} else if (pi==0) { //Child process
    char* argv[] =  {"new string", variableToChange, NULL};
    dup2(fd[1],1); //You connect to the pipe in input mode
    execve("newstringchildprocess", argv, environ);
    printf("Shouldn't execute this\n");
    exit(1);

} else{ //Father process
    int nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
    printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

And the other c file just need to focus on its logic and not communication:

```
printf("Enter new string: ");
printf(variableToChange, (strlen(variableToChange) + 1));
int charCount = sizeof argv[0];
variableToChange = (char*) malloc(charCount);
wait(NULL);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

---

**EDIT**

Anyways, you could replace in the `dup2` the file descriptor you want to use, and instead of being directly connected to the standard output it could be connected to the pipe in another fd. It's a bit harder but gives you a little bit more flexibility. Remember that another created pipe in the other .c file is not the same one than the father.

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Fork error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
} else if (pi==0) { //Child process
    char* argv[] =  {"new string", variableToChange, NULL};
    execve("newstringchildprocess", argv, environ);
    printf("Shouldn't execute this\n");
    exit(1);

} else{ //Father process
    int nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
    printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

And the other c file just need to focus on its logic and not communication:

```
printf("Enter new string: ");
write(4,variableToChange, (strlen(variableToChange) + 1)); // I put 4 as I assume it is where the input of the pipe is, as i think you can't access fd[1] form this file
int charCount = sizeof argv[0];
variableToChange = (char*) malloc(charCount);
wait(NULL);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: That makes sense. But I should have added more context but I'm making a shell that will create the child process upon the user entering a specific string. How would I incorporate that functionality into this because it seems the child process execve will only execute if pid == 1 using your example. Also how would I find where the input of the pipe is because I don't pass it as an argument to the child process?

Comment: That's good. I worked a lot with shells. The first option works for a shell. Do you know that when using ````pid=fork()```` pid will be 0 in the child process and the child's pid on the father process? That is how you make the parent simply wait for the child while the child simply execute the given command.
The input of the pipe is at the given file descriptor, as I showed you in the second option (at the edit). Although, if you are making a shell, it is highly recommended to use the first method, as you simply assign the child's input from the pipe and the output directly to standard output

Comment: If you need more clarification, I could edit my answer a little bit more extensively. Nevertheless if you found it usefull please feel free to upvote and accept my answer as valid. :)

Comment: I've edited my comment with more code @Román. I'm trying to include functionality for output, input redirection and exiting the shell but it seems no matter what I add in the pid==0 condition the shell always exits even when I try logic for only exiting in the exit conditional. The shell is in a while loop and the strings with any pipes are appended to a linked list data structure to be processed in the parent process file because i'm trying to have the shell include pipe operator functionality later on.

Comment: the execveErrorHandler function mainly just checks if execve fails and prints a string with strerror. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Also the code does not seem to work either from your example it still prints blank so just wondering what is wrong in my logic(removed your example code from the pid == 0 conditional as I wanted to test why the output redirection functionality was exiting the shell)

Comment: There is no "father".  Processes are genderless; it is "parent" and "child".

Comment: @RichardDesouza You have to understand how ````fork()```` works. I will give you some vital points: 1) When you use ````fork()````, you create another process (child process) with the same variables than the caller (parent process, as @William Pursell stated. Specifically, with the same file descriptor table. This means that you need to open your pipe before using fork, so both process will have access to it. 2) To control which process will control which code, ````fork()```` returns -1 in error case, 0 in child process and a number higher than 0 (child process' PID) in parent process.

Comment: When pid==0 after a fork, only the child process is going to execute this part, but the parent process containing the shell will not die. This means that for a shell to work correctly what you have to do is:
- Have a process reading user input. Parse it and obtain how many commands are there, how many pipes needed etc.
- In a loop in the parent process, create a pipe, then fork. At this point both processes will have the pipe in its fd table.
- Now, in the child process you can redirect the output, before ````execve````
- In the parent, close the unused ````fds```` and ````wait()````